# Inheritance in JavaScript with require.js: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, inheritance, requirejs

I'm running into Problems with require.js and probably the Prototypal inheritance. Here is my module:

```
define([], (function() {
  "use strict";
  var Player = function() {
    console.log("Constructor of the Player Object");
    this.audioObject = new Audio();        
  };
  Player.prototype = new Audio();
  return Player;
})); // define
```

Then I try to use play Method of the Audio-Object this way:

```
define(["jquery", "player"], (function($, Player) {
  "use strict";
  /**
  *  The controls for the player
  **/ 
  var Controls = function(player) {
    $(".play").click(function() {
      console.log("play");
      player.play();
    });
  };
  return Controls;
})); // define
```

When clicking on the button, Chrome throws the Error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I have been trying for hours now, reading similar problems here but most of them relate to jQuery what isnt the problem here I think. (I tried to define a method called Player.prototype.play() myself and that worked fine, but I don't think its the best way to rewrite all the methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because `Audio` has some hidden "under the hood" properties that aren't copied from the prototype when a new `Player` is instantiated.

When you call `player.play()`, `play` expects to run on an `Audio` instance, but it's running on a `Player` instance. Theoretically, there shouldn't be a problem here, because `Player` should be the same as an `Audio`, since its prototype is an `Audio` instance. However, `Audio` is a *host object*, which means it doesn't need to play by the rules of normal JavaScript objects.

That said, why are you even using an `Audio` instance for your `Player` prototype at all? Aside from being prone to weird behavior (as you're now observing), it seems totally unnecessary since you're already holding an `Audio` object in the `audioObject` property.

I don't fully understand your design, but why not use `audioObject`, e.g., call `player.audioObject.play()` here instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The reason I'm doing this is because thats how I understood inheritance in JS works. I thought I would get all the methods from the inherited object.
I tried your way but it resulted in another error:
Not allowed to load local resource:*link to file*

Comment: Ok now I fixed that problem and played a little with the code and ended up with *this.prototype = new Audio()* in  the constructor of my player and called play() with player.prototype.play() (which is what you suggested)- Thank you very much you helped me greatly and I can finally continue now.

Comment: @Envious Just so you know, using `prototype` like that might confuse people who read your code -- they might assume that an *instance* of `Player` is some kind of constructor. I definitely agree with you about using a property like that, but suggest you name it something different.